# MySql 3 tables, nested joins

Tags: mysql, join

```
Invoice
|    id   | invoice_date|
   123435   2016/02/09
   123436   2016/02/09
   123437   2016/02/09

Payments
|invoice_id| pmt_type| amount |
   123435       1       1000
   123435       2       2500
   123436       2       5000
   ...

Payments_legend
|type| description| 
   1      cash       
   2      check 
   3      credit
```

I'm in over my head with this one.  I need to pull daily transactions and thought it would be simple.  The problem I'm running into is a number of nested joins, unless there is a simpler way to do this.  On the surface, it really does seem simple.

The following gives me all the invoices I need...

```
SELECT id AS Invoice FROM invoice WHERE DATE(invoice_date) = DATE(NOW())
```

But that's where I get confused.  I need the sum for each payments.amount column grouped by invoice and separated into columns for each payments.pmt_type.  Yikes.

I need the report to be as follows...

```
id  sum(pmt_type=1)  sum(pmt_type=2)  sum(pmt_type=3)
```

It would look like...

```
Invoice  Cash  Check  Credit
123435   1000  2500   0
123436   0     5000   0
123437   0     0      7500
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ADDED THANKS TO NECULON'S HELP**

```
SELECT invoice.id,
sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 1, payments.amount, 0)) AS Cash,
sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 2, payments.amount, 0)) AS Chek,
sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 3, payments.amount, 0)) AS Credit,
sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 9, payments.amount, 0)) AS Warranty,
sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 10, payments.amount, 0)) AS Paypal,
sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 7, payments.amount, 0)) AS Refund,
(sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 1, payments.amount, 0))+sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 2, payments.amount, 0))+sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 3, payments.amount, 0))+sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 9, payments.amount, 0))+sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 10, payments.amount, 0))-sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 7, payments.amount, 0))) AS Total
FROM invoice
JOIN payments ON invoice.id = payments.invoice_id
WHERE DATE(invoice_date) = DATE(now())
GROUP BY invoice.id WITH ROLLUP
```

That gives me what I need.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use "IF" or "CASE". Something like this:

```
select 
  invoice.id,
  sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 1, payments.amount, 0)) cash,
  sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 2, payments.amount, 0)) check,
  sum(if(payments.pmt_type = 3, payments.amount, 0)) credit
from invoice
  join payment on invoice.id = payments.invoice_id
where date(invoice_date) = date(now())
group by invoice.id
```

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: Thanks nelucon!  That got me where I needed to be, with just a little tweaking.  I don't have the reputation to give you credit publicly, but suffice it to say that I appreciate your help immensely.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!